# Passing OPTIONS when I should Pass PUT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, angular-resource, http-method

I have the following configuration.

```
.config(config);

config.$inject = ["$httpProvider"];

function config($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];


  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
}
```

As for my `$resource`

```
.factory('Order', order)

order.$inject = ['$resource', "ApiEndpoint", "UserRecord"];

function order($resource, ApiEndpoint, UserRecord) {
  var id = null;

  UserRecord.retrieve().then(function (user) {
    id = user.user_id;
  })

  return $resource(ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json', {}, {
    update: {method: 'PUT', url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'orders.json'}
  });
}
```

Now when I call update like so

```
var params = { name: "new name" };

Order.update(params, {}, function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
})
```

My console renders `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.` as an OPTIONS request. If I run a POST request, everything works fine and as intended.

When I visit the server logs it verifies I'm running an OPTIONS request. How do I fix this to run a PUT request?

Comment: Why not just make the server respond to OPTIONS requests?

Comment: What is the url of the script and what is the url of the resource requested by the script? Please iclude protocoll and subdomain if they exist.

Comment: The url of the script and the url of the resource are different. localhost:8100 vs a regular domain. The domain is not subdomained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) request, which means that you try to connect to a server that is not your origin. Your origin is the server that serve your application.

Due to browser security policy, every request other than GET, requires a preflight handshake (OPTIONS), in which the non origin server, describes what headers, and methods he allows someone coming from origin X.

So the only way to skip preflight, is putting the resources you are accessing on the same server from which you serve the application.

Comment: I am able to make POST requests. Why is it that the POST request works but the PUT request does not?

Comment: That's interesting, can you add a plunker?

Comment: Not really. the project is NDA and I don't want to post anymore info. I feel like the code I've provided is sufficient to solve the answer. If there is a question about the code feel free to ask and I'll do my best to answer it.

Comment: The only question that I can ask is whether the server of the application and the server of data have the same origin?

Comment: Then it's a CORS request. It seems that POST can skip the preflight, see simple requests in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: POST preflight is based on your header information. If you are using Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, it is preflighted with OPTIONS as well.

Comment: There is no way for me to put the javascript application onto the same domain as the API server. I find this astonishing no one has solved the usage of PUT methods.

Comment: @JanisP If I set the content-type to urlencoded on a PUT request, would it work then?

Comment: @jason328 unfortunately no. PUT is always preflighted with OPTIONS if you are making CORS request. If you have access to server, make it just respond to options request.